# Change Google Forms "Rich Text Formatting" by apps script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-forms, richtext

Google added Rich text formatting to Google Forms titles and descriptions last month, but when I use Apps Script to create forms titles, I can't get any changes except "\n".
Would anyone be able to help me?

```
let questionHeader = form.addSectionHeaderItem();
questionHeader.setTitle("<b>"+question+"</b>\n"+"\b"+question+"\b0"); //test html format and test rtf format
```

[image]

Comment: Google Apps Script usually is behind the web apps, so you have to be patient. In the meantime you mind want to checkout the [Google Apps Script release notes](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/releases) and/or the [Google Developers Blog](https://developers.googleblog.com/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## UPDATE

As what [Ruben](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1595451/rub%C3%A9n) has commented, the **Google Apps Script** is indeed usually behind the web apps as of the moment.

Upon diving into Google's Public Tracker, a Google engineer has stated recently that [*"At the moment this feature is only supported by the UI version."*](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/239749101#comment2) on a submitted *Issue Tracker*. This means that you can **only** add rich text formatting in Google Forms titles and descriptions on the `https://docs.google.com/forms` web interface.

With that being said, *Google Feature Requests* for **Form API** & **Google Apps Script** have already been internally submitted to address this limitation with **rich text formatting**.

You may visit these submitted *Feature Request* public links below:

- [Google Forms rich text formatting using apps script](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/240105054)
- [Google Forms rich text formatting using forms API](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/240108930)

**To automatically get e-mail updates on these feature requests, you may ***"star"*** these public trackers:**

> [image]